# How to use CMDeviceMotion to detect how fast my device is traveling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, core-motion, cmmotionmanager

I am writing an iOS app and don't want to start detecting for shake events until after my device has reached a certain speed. I know how to use CMMotionManager to get the CMAccelerationData to detect for shake events but does anyone know what i should use to detect how fast my device is moving? Either CMDeviceMoting/userAcceleration/GPS... i am just cannot find what i should do. I am writing my app in swift but answers in Objective-C will suffice as well.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `CoreLocation` and use a `CLLocation`'s `speed` property. This requires the device's GPS, and will only work for somewhat large speeds.

Comment: Are you talking to me?

Comment: does 15mph sound relatively larger ? and that sounds like it could be what i am looking for. I just have never used CoreLocation before so i was not sure what its features were and also i was trying to stay away from using the GPS to keep battery life longer. but i will give it a try thanks

Comment: Yes. It seems to be the only solution for those speeds (but they have to be prolonged)

Comment: Battery life on am iPhone using GPS can be a killer, I just experienced that first-hand. Using the same app on an iPad I never had the problem. I would suggest watching the battery level and not running the user's battery fully down, that is what happened to be a couple of times and there are circumstances one *really* does not want the phone dead. Leave perhaps ~20%.

Comment: @ILikeTau My comment on the down vote was directed to the down voter, it seemed like a good answer to me.